# installation of Mapnik on macOS

Tags: python, mapnik

I have been trying to install Mapnik on MacOs (Sierra 10.12.6) and I am getting lost with what I think is a version problem. While I think I identified the problem, I do not know how to fix it, and have not found a way to do so over the internet.

Following the guidance of the Mapnik wiki, I first tried to install it from Brew.

```
brew install mapnik
```

The installation seems fine.

then on command line:

```
python
import mapnik
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mapnik
```

OK, according to my research, the issue comes from the fact that I am not using the right version of Python under which Mapnik was installed.

So I try again:

```
python3.7
import mapnik
>>> mapnik.Map(600,400)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'mapnik' has no attribute 'Map'
```

When I use the correct version, then Mapnik is imported correctly. But it seems it is not fully loaded?

I tried to re-install Mapnik through brew. I tried to install Mapnik from source as well as it is described on their website. Without success so far.

I am probably doing something stupid, Mapnik might not be installed at the right place, but really I am lost, trying so many things.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you using pip to install it into your  Python libraries?

Comment: hi cricket_007, thank you for your question. I just followed the guideline and used brew. I just used pip, but another error appears now .... Problem loading plugin library: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik/plugins/input/geobuf.input (dlopen failed - plugin likely has an unsatisfied dependency or incompatible ABI)